# how to create professional flowcharts in scribus?

Tags: scribus

I believe that scribus is powerful. But I really can't find any way to make professional clean connector arrows between the boxes. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

No, Scribus is not made for creating connectors and flowcharts.

But you can use your preferred flowcharts drawing tool, export to svg from there and import the result into scribus as a vector file.

Exporting to PDF or to a PNG and loading the result as an image could also be an option.

In the current development version (1.5.3), you can get the line to snap to rectangles, and it's a bit easier to draw small flowcharts.
But you still won't get the comfort you get from real flowchart programs.

Comment: My preferred workflow for flowcharts is using Libreoffice Draw and exporting as an SVG. If I remember correctly, Scribus converts SVG text to paths upon placement though, so one does need to be careful with fonts.